# Куда определить VM классы в патерне MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Дело в том, что VM получается уж больно жирная, у меня в форме много графиков, везде в примерах под каждую V только один VM, на сколько правильно будет разбить её на классы? А в VM это собирать вместе.

И как лучше организовать структуру папок для такого решения?

Comment: А у Вас каждый график представлен отдельным классом?

Comment: Класс графика один, OxyPlot. Но сами графики разные, где точками, где линиями, где без осей и т.п.

Comment: Т.е. у вас есть `VM1`, в которой объявлено свойство `PlotModel`, далее это свойство вы конфигурируете во `VM`?

Comment: У меня есть `MainWindowViewModel` в этом окне есть графики отображения температуры и влажности, для этого я выделяю два класса: `HumGrap` и `TempGrap` они объявляются как свойства которые уже юзаются через xaml. Правильно ли это? И в какую папку в структуре проекта мне их определять? Ведь их могут ещё использовать и другие VM

Comment: Разбивать 1 большой VM на 1 маленький и кучку дочерних VM. На каждый дочерний VM - по юзер контролу.